# Number of days between two dates for certain year

Tags: excel

How do i work out the number of days Fred and John worked during the period between Start and End, during the period of 2018?

I need a count of number of days, for Fred i would expect an output of 89 days, and John would equate to 41. I can work this out manually by doing date subtraction but with the real data there are 1000's of records, is there a way i can do a formula that captures people who worked at the start of 2018, and the end?

[image]

Comment: Used this Function  Syntax :- `DATEDIF(start_date, end_date, "d")`

Comment: That would solely provide the number of days between start and end, i need the number of days between start and end, counting only the days which occurred between 01/01/2018 and 31/12/2018. Very tricky!

Comment: Do a logical test of if the start date is before 1/1/2018, if it is before then use 1/1/2018, if after use the start date. Iden for end date but change logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula as per screenshot.

```
=DATEDIF(IF(AND(B4>=$B$1,B4<=$C$1),B4,$B$1),IF(AND(C4>=$B$1,C4<=$C$1),C4,$C$1),"d")
```

[image]

Comment: Also...`=DATEDIF(MAX($B$1,B4),MIN($C$1,C4),"d")`.